# Gridview with Dictionary

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview, dictionary

I've created a Dictionary like

```
Dictionary<Department,bool> dict= new Dictionary<Department,bool>();
```

here Department is a class and I have `Id,Name and Code` for the departments. And in the `bool` am sending whether the person is `HOD` or not.

Am adding the records to this Dictionary like

```
dict.Add(department,chkHOD.checked);
```

here the records are successfully added to the Dictionary and after this am binding the Dictionary to a GridView like

```
gridDept.Datasource=dict;
gridDept.Databind();
```

now the inserted records are displayed fine in the gridview. After this am storing this records in the 'StaffDepartments' table in my database. I have 3 columns in the 'Staffdepartments' table

```
1.StaffId(PK - has link with the Staff table)
2.DepartmentId(PK - has link with the Department table)
3.IsHOD.
```

here the records are stored fine in the database.No problem in adding the records into the database.

I have some questions here

****1.How can check whether the DepartmentId is already there in the Dictionary before adding to it.
2.When am editing the staff detail how can I delete the Selected Department from the Dictionary by checking  the checkbox in Gridview rows.(here the records are coming from the database, so when I click delete button the records should be deleted in the database as well)****

if its a List instead of Dictionary, I can get the DepartmentId by

```
int departmentId = (int)gridDept.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["DepartmentId"];
```

but in Dictionary i dunno how to do the same with Key and Value pairs....can anyone help me here.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? I've added the tag, I hope it's not wrong.

Comment: of course its ASP.NET...thanks for adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can check whether the DepartmentId is already there in the
>   Dictionary before adding to it.

You *could* use this:

```cs
if (!dict.Keys.Any(d => d.DepartmentId == department.DepartmentId))
    dict.Add(department,chkHOD.checked);
```

But something is wrong here. If your real key is the `DepartmentId` and not the `Department` (object identity) you should make it the key in the dictionary. For example, you could define a helper class:

```cs
public class DepartmentBindingHelper
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

An then define a dictionary like this:

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<int, DepartmentBindingHelper>();
```

And add the objects this way to the dictionary:

```cs
if (!dict.ContainsKey(department.DepartmentId))
    dict.Add(department.DepartmentId, new DepartmentBindingHelper
    {
        DepartmentId = department.DepartmentId,
        Department = department,
        Checked = chkHOD.checked
    });
```

Then you can bind only the value collection to the grid:

```cs
gridDept.Datasource = dict.Values;// it's an IEnumerable<DepartmentBindingHelper>
gridDept.Databind();
```

And your code to retrieve the `DepartmentId` from a row would work without changes:

```cs
int departmentId = (int)gridDept.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["DepartmentId"];
```

Comment: @Shanish: There was a bug in the first code snippet, I needed to add a `!` = "Not". I've corrected the code.

Comment: my key is Id not DepartmentId or Department, is it possible to get the Id without creating the helper class

Comment: I tried giving like int departmentId = (int)gridDept.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Id"]; but it shows error like "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: @Shanish: What is `Id`? I don't see this in your question.

Comment: actually when I put the breakpoint, I can see the three properties in dict dictionary, they are Id,Code and and Name....how can I get the Id

Comment: sorry its Id only not DepartmentId, I edited this in the question, check it

Comment: @Shanish: You could try `...DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Key.Id"]`. I'm not sure though if such dotted paths will work.

Comment: @Shanish: But the error indicates that `row.RowIndex` is out of range. I don't think that it has to do with the parameter of `Values[...]`.

Comment: @Shanish: I don't know. Maybe ask another question which focusses on this error *"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"*.